# Back button navigation on certain pages doesn't work at once, but after several hits

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, navigation

Why does it happen that when i press back button (browser back) the referrer page doesn't load immediately, but after several times hitting it. I know it is a browser history that holds that data, so what is making history to become invalid - duplicate or something?
On pages we have a saveral Ajax calls.
Also that bbehaviour is not on all pages, but only some.
Our pages are messy, that makes more difficult to find out why.
No matter, I ask this question here, and hope for some answers that can lead me to found out and clear the issue.

Can it be because of alert on page load?

Thank you,
Dejan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of researching on this issue I have gathered some facts that I want to share new and here with you.

There are many plugins for many things and some of them are using feature called pushState you can read more about it here: [Adding and modifying history entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries). With this feature those plugins are actively modifying browser history. After figuring that out I was able to resolve some issues that we have in our system. So if you ever find strangely that you can't browse back just look at documentation of specific plugin and disable that feature. I personally think that this feature is useful only if you are building "one page" site without much navigation needed between pages.